# Was my account reset?

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow, user-accounts

The last time I logged in on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) I had more than 15 reputation and I had some badges like Suffrage, Supporter, Citizen Patrol, Teacher. I had posted a question as well. Today when I logged in I was shocked to find I have no reputation, no badges, no question, I just found activity of those in my notification area and my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2046062/karan-dare?tab=badges) also shows me as being a member since today.

What might have caused this? Is it a bug perhaps?

Please see attached screenshot i don't how i can show all notification from this area
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like you have logged in today with different email id than the last one.

Comment: no i am always loggin using facebook

Comment: @KaranDare Do you happen to remember what the question was you asked? Are you still able to find it on the site?

Comment: yeah i got question is still in notification area but not exists the question name is "What does [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] in .htaccess RewriteRule mean?"

Comment: Hmm, don't have enough rep [to see that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323003/what-does-e-http-authorizationhttpauthorization-in-htaccess-rewriterule). Seems to be deleted as a result of moderation. I'm sure a mod will come along, or perhaps a higher rep user can provide some insight.

Comment: @Bart That account (id: 1814629) is actually deleted...

Comment: @Mysticial yep, it was nuked in "Jan 11 at 15:47".

Comment: but why my account is deleted ?? if its deleted then its stackoverflow's **bug** it still showing deleted account's notifications

Comment: @KaranDare only moderator or developer can answer that. Please fill [this form](http://stackoverflow.com/help/other), put your email and under "How can we help you?" explain and include link to [this deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13323003/447356) for reference.

Comment: ok thanks @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: I looked, but I don't see anything that would explain why you saw notifications from the previous account. Sometimes a botched merge leaves remnants in the areas we (mods) can see, but nothing there. A dev will need to take a look at this.

Comment: Account go poof.  Wasn't me, nobody saw anything, I didn't do it.  I blame casperOne, myself.

Comment: i have edited my question please see i have attach screenshot of my screen and please restore my everything of stackoverflow profile

Comment: @Won't still my account not restored on stackoverflow please let me know what i should do i have already submitted this form http://stackoverflow.com/help/other but didn't getting any response from team